# Trigonometric integral evaluates to factorial

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I would like to prove the integral identity $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\cos(x)} \cos(nx - \sin(x)) \, dx = \frac{2\pi}{n!}$$ One approach is to interpret this as the real part of a complex exponential integral and see that it is picking off Fourier coefficients. However, I'm curious whether there is a more "direct" approach using elementary calculus.

Comment: The integrand reminds me of the integral expression for the [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel.27s_integrals).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
I & =\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\cos(x)}\cos(nx-\sin(x))dx = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{\cos(x)}e^{inx-i\sin(x)}dx = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{inx}e^{\cos(x)-i\sin(x)}dx\\
& = \int_0^{2\pi}e^{inx}e^{e^{-ix}}dx
\end{align}
Setting $z=e^{ix}$, we have $dz = ie^{ix}dx = izdx$. Hence,
\begin{align}
I &  = \oint_{\vert z \vert=1} z^n e^{1/z} = \oint_{\vert z \vert=1} z^ne^{1/z} \dfrac{dz}{iz} = -i\oint_{\vert z \vert=1} z^{n-1}e^{1/z}dz = -i(2\pi i) \dfrac1{n!} = \dfrac{2\pi}{n!}
\end{align}